# Debug in visual studio code is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging

Launch Configuration

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible Node.js debug attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach",
            "port": 5858
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/app.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am getting the following error while debugging my react code in visual studio code. Actually I have created the project with node+react and use visual studio as IDE and want to debug my code. I have tried a lot but not able to success to debug my code.

```
Debugging with legacy protocol because Node.js v6.10.2 was detected.Program path uses differently cased character as file on disk; this might result in breakpoints not being hit.
node --debug-brk=21730 --nolazy src\app.js 
    Debugger listening on [::]:21730
    e:\reactjs\reactFacebook\my-app\src\app.js:1
    (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React, { Component } from 'react';
                                                                  ^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
        at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
        at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
        at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
        at Timeout.Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:604:10)
        at ontimeout (timers.js:380:14)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:244:5)
```

Comment: Probably related to [VS Code issue #24764](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24764). As mentioned in the issue, try add `"protocol": "inspector"` in your `launch.json`.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved it by adding below code inside the function which I want to debug:

```
debugger;
```

and debugging started.
Happy coding!!

Answer (score 2):

For me, debugging is only possible with cwd set to

`"cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/src"`

Answer (score 1):

Very simple solution is -> just uninstall debugger and delete launch.json file
After that reinstall debugger then start

Answer (score 1):

To start debugging in vs code without launch.json,

Goto File → Preferences → Settings → Extensions → Node Debug →[select ] "ON"

[image: Image-Enable debugger]

Comment: I don't have Node Debug section at all, under the Extensions

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, turns out the clue was in the console: **Debugging with legacy protocol because Node.js v6.10.2 was detected**.

I resolved it using the following steps:

- Shutdown VS Code
- Uninstall node
- Install node v5 using [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)
- Delete **node_modules** folder in project
- Re-open VS Code
- Run `npm install`

Place a breakpoint and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from .net core 3.1 to .net core 6 and debugging was not picking up my new controller methods. I had to update my launch.json program keyword under configurations to the correct location. I changed the value between Debug and Controllers.dll from netcoreapp3.1 to net6.0
[image]